# No se como manejar una "no seleccion" en un select

Tags: php

Tengo un `select` así:

```
<select multiple name="claseUsuario[]">
   <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
   <option value="2">Tipo 2</option>
   <option value="3">Tipo 3</option>
   <option value="4">Tipo 4</option>                    
</select>
```

después por `PHP` lo transfiero así:

```
$usuclase = $_POST['claseUsuario'];

if (isset($usuclase)) {
    foreach($usuclase as $claseUsuario){
      echo $claseUsuario;
    }
} else {
    $usuclase = '0';
}
```

El usuario puede no seleccionar nada, lo que me daría la opción de que sea otro tipo de usuario, pongamos el usuario `"0"...`

Ahora bien, algo estoy haciendo mal porque con el echo ese del `foreach` puedo ver cada valor cuando selecciona algo en el `select` pero cuando no selecciona nada me arroja este error:

> "Undefined index: claseUsuario"

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo ?

igual reemplazando por:

```
if (isset($_POST['claseUsuario'])) {

  foreach($usuclase as $claseUsuario){
    echo $claseUsuario;
  }
} else {
  $usuclase = ['0'];
}
```

tampoco anda...

Comment: El `isset` se realiza al `$_POST` antes de asignar a la variable `$usuclase` , es decir `if(isset($_POST['claseUsuario']){ ....}`

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: @MNibor la última actualización no funciona porque no estás haciendo la asignación a `$usuclase` dentro del `if`

Comment: @alv $usuclase = $claseUsuario; adentro del foreach ?

Comment: Antes de esa línea deberías hacer `$usuclase = $_POST['claseUsuario'];`. Porque no se habría asignado `$usuclase` pero lo estarías usando dentro del `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, estás usando una variable indefinida antes de comprobar si está definida, tu código debe quedar así:

```
if (isset( $_POST['claseUsuario'])) {  //¿Existe este post?
   $usuclase = $_POST['claseUsuario']; //Usamos la variable dentro de POST

   foreach($usuclase as $claseUsuario){ //podemos iterar seguramente porque SI existe
      echo $claseUsuario;
    }

} else {
    $usuclase = '0'; 
}
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh bien ahora entiendo... ahora bien... si no existe es valido que le ponga a $usuclase = '0' ? y otra cosa... ese echo que tengo adentro del for each... esta al divino boton... lo puse como bandera para ver si levantaba los valores seleccionados... (disculpame pero estoy arrancando con esto y hay muchas cosas que estoy aprendiendo)

Comment: Si te sirve de algo que tenga 0, está bien pero también puedes simplemente no usarlo. En PHP pasa comúnmente que usamos `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` o `var_export` para ver como se comportan nuestros scripts, a me gusta usar un bloque `try / catch` y genero excepciones cuando quiero ver la variable. Es cuestión de gustos supongo :)

Comment: probe ese cambio que me has dicho y en los parametros que pasa a la base de datos (y pasa valores) me arroja error 'mbravo', '$2y$10$khENaDvC...', 'MARIO BRAVO', 'mrobin@gmail.co...', 0, 'c29a5dcb0e835a2...', 2, **Array**) en el ultimo valor pone ARRAY !!!

Comment: has un `var_dump($_POST)` para saber que valor de ese array debes usar.